# UIGestureRecognizer limited to a CGRect

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view that shows a menu with one table with a right transparent background to cover the rest of the view, I can hide the menu when the right side is tapped but then the table rows can't be hitted.

-frame full screen

```
self.menuVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
self.menuVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

-Gesture

```
        self.tapBackground = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.hideTapMenu))
        self.asda = CGRect(x: self.table.bounds.width, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapBackground)


        self.addChildViewController(self.menuVC)
        self.view.addSubview(self.menuVC.view)
```

Hide Menu

```
 func hideTapMenu (gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = gesture.location(in: self.view)

    if asda.contains(p){
        hideMenu()
    } else {
        print("Touching menu")
    }

}


func hideMenu(){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.menuVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: -UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    }) {(finished) in

        self.menuVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    AppDelegate.isMenuShown = true
}
```

[this is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZmyr.png)

Can I just add a GestureRecognizer to the second CGRect?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't add a Gesture to a CGRect. You can only add it to a View.

Comment: You can add one more transparent view with required CGRect b/w menuVC.view and self.view, And add gesture to that view

Comment: @Pablo You can just use 3rd party SideMenu. For example: [jonkykong/SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu/)

Comment: I am i bit new with iOS and i don't want to make it too difficult, but i will try Abhishek recomendation. Thanks for this 3rd party sidemenu it's so cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply deal with it by using [`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate). Implement its `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` method in your code to return `true` - that way your gesture recognizer will work, but it will also allow other gestures to be recognized. That way the table's internal gesture recognizer should work normally.

Code:

```
// add this to initializing code to set its delegate to self
self.tapBackground.delegate = self
```

Delegate implementation:

```
extension YourViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the main view controller to set blurry effect, you can use another view like image view and add that gesture to image view. 
Table view should be the top most view.